# Test method that has a @PreAuthorize annotation

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a controller end point that has an annotation for auth:

```
  @PreAuthorize("@permissionService.hasPermission(#appUser.getId(), #businessId, 'READ')")
  @GetMapping("/feature_flags/{featureFlagId}/business/{businessId}")
  public BaseResponse<FeatureFlagAccess> checkBusinessFeatureAccess<(..args>) {
    ...some code
  }
```

I've written unit tests for the method itself, but I'm not sure how to test the @PreAuthorize part, is this doable here or does it have to be an integration test?

If it helps, I'm running tests with the following:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

Comment: Do this with an integration test / mockmvc. Spring does a lot of magic behind scenes and it's easy for that to go wrong.

Comment: Combining `@ExtendWith` with `@RunWith` doesn't make sense. The first is for JUnit 5, while the second is for JUnit 4. You should only use one (the one that matches the JUnit version you want to use).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel thanks for the note, I didn't realize this.